# I can see nothing when I call my.domain.name::5984/_utils/ Couchdb installing

Tags: linux, couchdb

I can see nothing when I call 'my.domain.name::5984/_utils/. For couchdb installing I used this script:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/640288/how-to-install-latest-couchdb-on-ubuntu

Please tell me what I have to do to see a result I am looking for. I had opened port but I see this http://prntscr.com/k55qox

Answer (score 1):

To access CouchDB externally, you need to change the `bind_address` to `0.0.0.0`

This can be done manually by configuring your `chttpd` bind_address to `0.0.0.0`

Altough, it's recommended to setup your cluster. To do so, refer to the [cluster_setup documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cluster/setup.html#cluster-setup).